# Should a comma be used here?

Tags: commas

On a website I display a welcome message when a user logs in. Currently it looks like this (for example)

> Welcome [The Persons Username]!

But I was thinking that maybe it should be like this:

> Welcome, [The Persons Username]!

Which one is correct?

Comment: There's no correct; it's a matter of style. Your user is going to ignore your message anyway.

Comment: I'd choose version 2

Comment: I'd use the latter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the messages are correct.

> Welcome [The Persons Username]!

Would be said without a pause and

> Welcome, [The Persons Username]!

Would be said like welcome (slight pause) [The Persons Username]!

Ultimately, it might just be a stylistic choice, use whichever looks better.